# Efficient way to move water pumping vs circulation

Tags: fluid-dynamics

I have a basic question about efficiency of pumping.

If I have a well of 100 meters depth, but water filled till top, and I want to circulate the water. What will be most energy efficient.  A) Pumping the water to 100 meters head and then discharging the water at top of that well but below water level or B) having a discharge pipe run all the way down to the same level as intake pipe.

[image]

Questions

1) with option A, If the well is filled to the top, and discharge point is below water level.  Then will the Total Dynamic Head be 10m or 110m and what will be energy required pump 1KG of water.

2) with option B, what will be the energy required  ?

3) any other major influences on the pumping energy ? like pressure if the intake depth increases but water level remains same ?

Comment: Is this 'clean' water? If you want to circulate particulates, then you need to make sure the inlet and outlet are as far apart as possible.  For that matter, if you want to reach some sort of equilibrium (e.g. temperature), for the same reason you want to maximize the homogenization of the volume.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both will be of the same efficiency. It only matters how far you raise water above the surface. Where you take it from within the bulk of the water is irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the answers from Alex and Dirk, I guess this should be the right way to look at this problem [image]